# Get name of control that mouse over it(win32)

Tags: winapi, mouseevent

I have a win32 program.
I want to change status text when mouse come over particular control
in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`:

```
wsprintf((LPWSTR)szBuf, TEXT("Mouse position: %d, %d"), LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        SendMessage(hWndStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(LPSTR)szBuf);
```

but it only gives me mouse position.

Comment: Windows don't have names in win32.  You'll need at least WindowFromPoint().  From there it is up to you to figure out a name from that handle.

Comment: Correct: "name" is the wrong term.  But if you're interested in knowing when the mouse is over a *particular* window, then handling an event is much more efficient than polling the location.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong suggestion: use something higher-level than Win32, if at all possible.  MFC, VB ... *anything*.

To answer your question, however, you should be able to use a combination of TrackMouseEvent () and WM_HOVER:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=290195